# Image Responses in Java - HTTPServer

Tags: java, image, httpserver

I have a web server in java like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 0);
   server.createContext("/", new HomeHandler());
   server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
   server.start();
}
```

And here's the `HomeHandler`:

```
class HomeHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
    String filepath = "C:\\Public\\home.html";
        String response = getPage(filepath);
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

and finally here's the function `getPage()`:

```
private static String getPage(String page){
    String toret = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(page));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            toret += sCurrentLine;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return toret;
}
```

But when my home page loads, it has an image in it so the browser makes another request to my server for the image, I made a similar handler for images which does the same thing, i.e, calls the function getPage() passing in as arguments the image's filepath...

But when it actually runs in the browser it doesn't show the image. But it correctly tells the size of the image when I open the image alone in the new tab (Google Chrome is my Browser, the latest one as of today)..

Comment: If you put in your `getPage` function code which saves to file all the data going to be sent to client, what do you get? By the way, is using `String` OKay to store binary image data?

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Answer (score 1):

Images are binary data and cannot be passed via `String` (which cannot store/yield specific byte sequences). So there use `byte[]` directly. Nice would be setting the response type `Content-Type: application/jpeg` or `png` or `gif`.

As an aside, your code is using the encoding of your platform. For a specified encoding, say the universal Unicode:

```
getBytes() // Platform dependant
getBytes("UTF-8") // Specified

new FileReader(file) // Platform dependant
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),) // Platform dependant
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8") // Specified


new FileWriter(file) // Platform dependant
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)) // Platform dependant
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8") // Specified

byte[] bytes;
new String(bytes) // Platform dependant
new String(bytes, "UTF-8") // Specified
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to implement a handler that send back the the UI the image:

```
private void forwardImage(HttpExchange exchange, String imagefilename) throws IOException {

    byte[] result = readSmallBinaryFile(imagefilename);

    if (result == null) {       
        // resource_not_found_error
    }


    exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE_IMG);
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, message.length);
        os = exchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write(message);
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }

    return os;
}
```